# How can Linux VMs detect usb smart cards on Windows laptops?

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication

I am trying to set up ssh authentication on Azure/AWS hosted Linux VMs with USB Feitain smart cards. I have ran into a problem because the virtual machines need to be able to read the smart cards on the USB port. Do anyone have any ideas to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you do this if Windows was on both ends?

Comment: Its actually easier for windows to use smartcards with RDP

Comment: Could a local Linux client use one of these smartcards for its own authentication

Answer (score 0):

The VMs in public cloud does not have access to your laptop's USB port. You may use ssh authentication based on the certificate inside your smartcard.

Please have a look at [Putty-CAC](http://risacher.org/putty-cac/) project.

[Here](https://playbooks.idmanagement.gov/piv/engineer/ssh/) there is a detailed setup tutorial